# Как удалить метапакеты с помощью ansible и chocolatey?

Tags: ansible, chocolatey

Ansible настроен на управление windows 10, установлена chocolatey (пакетный менеджер для windows) Подскажите, как с помощью модуля ansible win_chocolatey, win_chocolatey_config и win_chocolatey_feature
Локально на управляемом хосте эта команда choco uninstall <имя пакета> -x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно [оф документации](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_chocolatey_module.html) это будет выглядеть так:

```yaml
- name: Uninstall git
  win_chocolatey:
    name: git
    state: absent

- name: Uninstall multiple packages
  win_chocolatey:
    name:
      - procexp
      - putty
      - windirstat
     state: absent
```